# Windows 8: docking/snapping windows to more than left or right

Tags: windows-8, productivity, aero-snap

Anybody know of a program that'll allow me to dock windows (non-metro apps) to more than just the left or right of the desktop?

I have a 27 inch 1440p monitor that I bought with the idea of being able to work on simultaneous things on the screen (I prefer this to having multiple monitors). It'd be great if when I was working with 3 windows I could maybe snap one to the left, then have the remaining ones take up the vertical space remaining on the right equally.

I can obviously do this by grabbing each window and resizing/moving as necessary, but it's not very convenient.

What I had in mind was something like what you have when developing software with WPF on .Net where you can continuously dock controls to either left, top, right, bottom and each control is arranged according to remaining space in the dock panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exercise fine control over the location of your windows with [WinSplit Revolution](http://winsplit-revolution.com/). After it is installed, move windows around with `Ctrl+Alt+Numpad`.

WinSplit uses a system where pressing the same button more then one time allows you to adjust the size in the position you have chosen, so pressing `Ctrl+Alt+4` one time would move the window to the  left side of your screen at 50% size, and pressing `Ctrl+Alt+4` twice would move it to the left 33%. This is all adjustable. (Right click the icon → choose layout settings)

To get the windows in the specific example you describe, you would

- Select the left window and press `Ctrl+Alt+4` twice
- Select the middle window and press `Ctrl+Alt+5` twice
- Select the right window and press `Ctrl+Alt+6` twice

The end result:
[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, but suits my practical needs perfectly! For some reason I can't get Drag'N'Go to work, though, and no forums on the website that I can see.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. Restarted windows and it's working fine now. That and upping the detection radius to 500 for Drag'N'Go and I'm happy with this software.